# Dropbox API says conflict while there is no conflict

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I try to upload files using Dropbox API:

```
var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
                            autorename:false,
                            path: remote_path+"/"+Path.GetFileName(localfile),
                            mode: WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                            body: mem);
```

when `autorename` is `false`the api throws an exception having this error : **path/conflict/folder/..** but when I turn autorename to true then it uploads successfully!

I am sure the target folder is empty on Dropbox (web & local)

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the same account you're looking at on web and local? Try calling `Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync` to check the account and `Files.GetMetadataAsync` on that path first to check what the API sees in the way.